# joining table on itself to copy column matching same product

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy a product description to the same product_id but in a different language (USA and Canada) both are in english so that is why I am copying them over.

I am however getting 0 rows updated. Here is my sql:

```
UPDATE products_description pd1  
JOIN products_description pd2 on pd1.products_id = pd2.products_id and pd2.language_id = 3
SET pd1.products_description_second = pd2.products_description_second
WHERE pd2.language_id = 1
```

- language_id = 1 is the Canadian English
- Language_id = 3 is the american English

When I run the sql though i get 0 rows affected.

Here is a picture of the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ngmJ.png

Comment: That is some modern phpMyAdmin'ing you've got going on there!

Comment: Yes we like to stay up to date with the times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think problem is testing language_id.  You're joining on `pd2.language_id = 3` and using `WHERE pd2.language_id = 1`, so trying to join the rows on language_id '3' where language_id is '1'.  One of these should probably be `pd1.language_id`.